# It's possible to create a 360 Video in blender?

Tags: video

like this one http://www.airpano.com/360Degree-Video.php?3D=Video-Bromo you can turn around...If I draw a scene how can I render a video like that? and wich format is it?

Comment: Yes, this is quite possible. Somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13853/599

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what you are trying to make the 3D video of. Are you looking to render a 3D video of a scene in blender, or stitch together footage into a 3D video?

Answer (score 2):

There is a great App [VRAIS](http://vrais.io/) which uses Blender and they provide a [tutorial](http://vrais.io/tutorial) of how to render stereoscopic panoramas for this App:

> - Render dimension: 2048x1024 for starters, and for final rendering 4096x2048 (just type in 200% in the render percentage).
> - In the Render Layers Panel, enable "Views"
> - Set your camera to Panoramic. Choose "Equirectangular" from the dropdown menu
> - Enable "spherical stereo" (Only available in Dalai's version)
> - set the pivot point to „Center“

Or you could watch some not so static [360° Videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzuqhhs6NWbgTzMuM09WKDQ). Pedro Gaspar made a [tutorial](http://pedrogaspar.weebly.com/blog/making-a-360-video-on-blender-to-be-published-on-youtube) of how to create them in Blender. Blenderrendersky already [created some videos](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/04/01/more-360-bge-footage/) in the BGE with this method.

Comment: I would LOVE to have this revisited. It's early 2019 and VRAIS and Pedro Gaspar's KolorEyes are defunct or shuttered end of 2018. Blender 2.8 is out (BETA), AR and VR are working hard to rise!!! And when I was about to post this question, StackExchange suggested this post. Any news?

Answer (score 2):

As of Blender 2.9 (writing in Jan 2021), you'll still need to use Cycles in order to get a 360 equirectangular render effect.

First, some details:

- This is exactly like any other scene, and renders to a rectangular video in a standard format. In other words, you can watch it on a regular ol' movie screen (or Quicktime with a bowl of microwave popcorn, if you're still reading this during the times of COVID-19).
- You will need to add some additional metadata to the render that currently *cannot* be done in Blender. Google has a tool called [spatialmedia](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/) which inserts this metadata so that 360º video players understand how to render it (rather than just rendering the distorted view).

### Rendering the video

Create your scene just as you usually do. Set your renderer to Cycles, and select your camera.

[image]

Here are the settings you want. Note that you want to switch to `Equirectangular`, which is not the default.

[image]

This step is important! Change the render aspect ratio to a 2:1 ratio: In other words, the width of your render should be twice the height. If you don't have your powers-of-two memorized like an insane person, then this is a good reminder that Blender fields accept math expressions as well.

[image]

Run a test-render. You should get something that distorts your image like this:

[image]

Your viewer, looking straight ahead, will see the CENTER of this image. If they turn 180º and face behind themselves, they'll see what's in the leftmost pixels of this image (identified with the right-most; remember you're in a sphere!). If they look straight up, they'll see (extremely low-res!) views of the topmost rows of pixels, and if they look down, the bottommost.

**Render the animation.** Whether you render directly to mp4 or through frames→video compositor→mp4, the next step expects a single video file.

### Injecting Metadata

Download the [Spatial Media Metadata Injector](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/releases/tag/v2.1) for your OS. I hate that this is a separate step, sorry.

Press <kbd>Open</kbd> and select your video.

[image]

Select the first checkbox, this is a 360 video.

Press Inject, and save the video (with metadata) as a new file.

---

You can now upload this file to your favorite 360-video service, like YouTube, and it will automatically detect that this is a pano-360 video. Neat!

Fun fact: You can also use an equirectangular render like this as an Environment map in Blender itself. Render your scene inside itself! w0w0w0w!