# Why do 360° videos look low res when uploaded to Youtube?

Tags: animation, export, video

I've been in the process of making a 1min 360° video for YouTube. I had already run some tests to make sure I knew how to make it 360° from blender to its final delivery, so getting it panoramic is no problem.

I've running some tests just to check the video quality is alright but it seems no matter what I do it comes out looking low res once uploaded to YouTube. I've used several templates for rending from online users and I've tried it in 720p, 1080p, and 1440p but it always comes out looking poor once I've got it uploaded. My normal animation I can export looking just fine. Where do you think I might be going wrong?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48188/2843

Comment: The youtube player only displays only a small portion of your video at a time (so you can pan around). Hence, only a small portion of the total resolution is used at one time. There's not much you can do except provide even more resolution, but I'm not sure if youtube even supports 360 videos at, say, QHD resolution..

Comment: But other folk don't seem to have my problem too bad, this one for example seems to have acceptable resolution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx4xyMn7sCQ

Comment: Have you made sure that you set it to the highest resolution when viewing on Youtube?

Comment: Yeah I always put it to HD and highest. Still nay good :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not really about blender, but about youtube's settings and compression

Comment: You need to render it in 4k resolution to get a 1080p quality in 360 view

Answer (score 1):

This has been driving me nuts too, haven't come up with a fix yet and I'm outputting using Premier Pro: unsharp mask, color correction, 4k resolution, ~30bps bitrate and 59.94 fps.  Looks great on my computer, then uploads to YouTube like garbage.

Even 1080p/60fps renders terribly on YouTube and you would think this would be their default 'let's make this look as good as possible' configuration they'd want to get right in-terms of their compression.

Johnpbuck submitted a video that looks decent I guess, but in my mind it's not a real world example.  Here's the quality I'm trying to get to without buying new cameras (which I don't think will solve the problem considering how good my cameras perform BEFORE YouTube) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LByJ9Q6Lddo

The only trick I can suggest that others may not have tried yet is forcing rendering of your video at 59.94fps.  My cameras don't go that high but YouTube does grant a higher bitrate during uploading to a frame rate beyond 30.

Comment: If you're not sure you can answer the question, comments section would perhaps be better. :)

Comment: True, sorry just venting about my render/upload frustrations.  My 'fix' is waiting on YouTube to up their game, which will happen, it's just a question of when.  If Vimeo could jump in and start supporting 360° video it would be a huge game-changer.

Comment: It's okay, just keep it in mind next time, and don't worry, if you ever get called out for doing something wrong, it's never personal, and happens to pretty much everyone at first.