# Object rotation in 360

Tags: objects

Is it possible to make an object rotate, when the viewer rotates the screen on YouTube in 360? So, it wouldn't depend on the camera, rather than the viewer himself/herself.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48188/935) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: You mean a video like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eppTvwQNgro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to make it so that when a user rotates their view in YouTube 360 (I.e. Tilts their phone), rather than the camera rotating, just an object on the screen will? This is not possible due to the nature of YouTube 360. A 360 video is simply a very distorted normal video, which YouTube analyzes and molds into a 360 sphere, which the user is inside of. This means that a 360 video is still a normal video, and videos aren't interactive in the way you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Keyframe the rotation on the axis you like.
For example

- Object mode, select object,
- select frame 0, insert keyframe rotation
- select frame 40, rotate z 180, insert keyframe rotation
- select frame 80, rotate z 180, insert keyframe rotation
- play the animation frames  0-80 and witness the revolution
- improve the animation

If you need a video tutorial please state so in the comments.

Comment: Yes, please.                                            Even if I'm not sure about the result .-.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHdTUJBs7so  .... a few dozen for you to watch

Comment: I don't want to rotate an object, instead I want the viewer to rotate an object while watching the video; so, if I am the viewer and I am watching the video on YouTube and I, for example, rotate the video itself, the object and only it will rotate with the viewer.

Comment: When you clarify a requirement put the clarification in the original question.  Then you can request people to look at a new clarification.  Then after that clarification you can delete your comment here.  Then I will delete mine.  Clarification should be directed at all readers.