# Background is not moving with respect to camera position

Tags: animation, texturing, camera, world

I have a simple animation where the camera is moving to the planet's location.

The issue that I'm having is that the background is not moving with respect to the camera's location. What is the proper way to achieve this?

[image]

<sup>*The camera is moving to toward the spinning planet, but the background is not moving in respect to the camera's change of position.*</sup>

[image]
 <sup>*The node setup of the world's environment to create stars.*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*The movement of the camera in this scene.*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The world background is assumed to be infinitely far away. (see [this link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/volume.html?highlight=volume%20world#volume-world)).

In order to have some change for the stars you would need to generate them like in this image:

[image].

In this case the stars are generated using an icosphere used as emitter. See: [Animating a masked sphere with "star" particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47954/animating-a-masked-sphere-with-star-particles)

Comment: I added the particle system, and it shows in the viewport but not in the render. Any ideas how I would get these particles to render?

Comment: Did you assign a material to the object used as particles?

Comment: Yes, an emission shader, and I set the particle system to use that sphere under dupli object with scale checked. When I rotate out of camera view in render view it works fine, I can see all the particles, just not in the camera.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm an idiot. The particle system was outside the camera's clipping plane, after scaling down the emitter, the stars are visible.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve what you want by adding a texture coordinate note and a mapping node to the vector input of your noise texture. Connect the generated coordinate to the mapping input and then the mapping output to your texture. Now in the mapping node you can animate the location values to make it look like the stars are moving past you.