# Is there anyway to make a constellation by only lighting up vertices of an object

Tags: vertices, wireframe

I am trying to make a constellation of an outline I made, but I can't find a way to only have the vertices glow.

Comment: What render engine are you using? If Blender internal you can try the *Halo* materials, in Cycles I don't think it is possible without some actual geometry

Comment: alternatives: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/stars-background-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47954/animating-a-masked-sphere-with-star-particles